# Abstract factory for dart (or similar construct)

Tags: dart, generics, inheritance, factory

In Dart, I'm managing collections that share a common property (e.g., all have the same value for attribute `x`). I also want to have access to some extra data regarding `x`. I wanted to achieve this using a generic manager in which `T` has the extra data. I'm loading the data from the entities and `T` from a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

```dart
class EntityManager<T extends MetaBaseClass> {
    final List<Entity> entities;
    final T meta;

    EntityManager({required this.entities, required this.meta});

    factory EntityManager.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        return EntityManager(
            entities: List<Entity>.from(map['entities']?.map((x) => Entity.fromMap(x))),
            meta: <this is where I am stuck>
        );
    }
}
```

Because `Entity` has the `fromMap` factory, it's easy to just generate a `List<Entity>`.
I thought I could do the same with `T` but since `T` is still a generic, it doesn't have this factory. My idea was to extend `T` with a base class that has an abstract factory so that `T` must have this factory as well but that does not seem to work either. I am starting to question this approach. Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Pass a callback to `EntityManager.fromMap` that returns a new `T` instance, and have `EntityManager.fromMap` call that.

Comment: @jamesdlin but how would I instantiate that `T`?

Comment: As I said, take a callback that does it.  The caller of `EntityManager.fromMap` would need to supply a function that returns a new `T` instance.

Comment: @jamesdlin I'm sorry, I can't quite follow. Could you post an example?

Comment: A caller would need to do something like `EntityManager<SomeType>.fromMap(map, constructor: SomeType.new)`.  `EntityManager.fromMap` would need to take an additional `constructor` parameter and would need to explicitly invoke it.